# Row and column labelling of matrixes in LaTeX

Tags: latex, matrix

How to add labels to the columns and rows (such as `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and the like) which go above and to the left (both outside) of the matrix, but are obviously aligned with said columns and rows?

An example matrix:

```
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
t   & 1-t &  -1 &  0  &  0  \\
0   &  t  & 1-t &  -1 &  0  \\
0   &  0  &  t  & 1-t &  -1 \\
-1  &  0  &  0  &  t  & 1-t \\
1-t &  -1 &  0  &  0  &  t
\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: `table` or `longtable` environments could be used instead of `pmatrix`.

Comment: Yeah. CTAN doesn't turn up anything that looks promising at all.

Comment: Hmmm... table looks like it could be a possibility, but I would much rather have the ability to keep the delimiters of pmatrix, since it is a matrix which corresponds to a knot diagram...

Comment: See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try the **kbordermatrix** package. Its documentation can be found [here](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf) (note that the package is not part of CTAN). It is more modern and advanced than good old **bordermatrix**. An example follows below:

```
\usepackage{kbordermatrix} % include package @ document preamble
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(} % change default array delimiters to parentheses
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}

% ...

\[
\kbordermatrix{
    \mbox{corner_text}&\alpha & \beta & \gamma & \delta \\ % column indices
    1 & t   & 1-t &  -1 &  0  &  0  \\
    2 & 0   &  t  & 1-t &  -1 &  0  \\
    3 & 0   &  0  &  t  & 1-t &  -1 \\
    4 & -1  &  0  &  0  &  t  & 1-t \\
    5 & 1-t &  -1 &  0  &  0  &  t
    % 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are row indices
}
\]
```

Comment: Note that I was able to use with kbordermatrix from MikTex without any trouble, despite not seeing it on CTAN.